# how to use kaminari with vue.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, vue.js, kaminari

Well, the question is: is there any possibility to use kaminari paginator with vue.js in ruby on rails project?
According to [kaminari tutorial](https://richonrails.com/articles/pagination-with-kaminari), I just can do this in my controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.page(params[:page])
  end
end
```

and in view:

```
<%= paginate @posts %>
```

But in case of vue.js you have to pass variable @posts in json format like:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render json: @versions }
end
```

to vue.js.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but you might want to use Vue.js Paginator instead of Kaminari (see https://hootlex.github.io/vuejs-paginator/)